# Qt create component from relative URL

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qqmlcomponent

In [the 4.8 docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdeclarativedynamicobjects.html#creating-a-component-dynamically), it is specified that:

> When using files with relative paths, the path should be relative to the file whereQt.createComponent() is executed.

So I use the following to create an object:

```
Qt.createComponent("./foo/bar.qml").createObject(_this)
```

But I get the error:

> QQmlComponent: Component is not ready

I have also tried (without luck) `"foo/bar.qml"`. Changing to `"foobar.qml"` works fine, with the directory structure:

```
./
 +--foo/
 |     `--bar.qml
 `--foobar.qml
```

I notice however that there is no mention of relative URLs in [the version 5 docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#createObject-method), so is there a new way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: Try to output `Component::errorString()` for more diagnostics

Comment: And don't they accept url in `file:///...` format?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is directly related to relative paths.  The "Component is not ready" error means that you're calling `createObject()` before the component is ready.  Instead, you need to listen for the component's `statusChanged` signal and create the object only when the status changed to `Component.Ready`.

Take a look at [Dynamic QML Object Creation from JavaScript](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html) for a complete example and more detail.

Comment: I also receive that error when I attempt to create from a nonexistent file though; hence my assumption.

Comment: @OllieFord If that's the case, I'd double check to make sure you're running the executable from the same path that the QML files are located in.

Comment: I must be, I'm using Qt Creator with the (incomplete) project structure as in OP. Opening from project root works fine, but from subdirectories does not.

Comment: Also, I can verify that it never becomes ready, by doing `while(cmpnt !== Component.Ready){};cmpnt.createObject(_this)`, which just hangs.